# On Notification Button Click Refresh Activity

Tags: android, notifications

I am implementing a TO DO app.
Consider a task created with a due date= NOW.
When the due date is reached, a notification is shown in the status bar with two buttons. DONE & DELETE.

When i click DONE, the task is marked completed in the database but the data in the application is reflected the DONE status.

This is because the OnResume() method is not called when the notification button (DONE) is clicked.

How to i call the OnResume of an activity after a notification button is clicked.

Comment: You mean to say you want to call you app from notification bar upon click of done button?

Comment: while i am using the app, i get a notification. So, i open the status bar and click the done button. now in the app, the listview data should refresh and reflect the done status.

Comment: Two solution either you control it via PendingIntent, and resuming your app refreshing view, else latch your listview with a cursor adapter setting up a observer on top of database, so when value changes you get a notification simple call notifyDataSetChanged ..

Comment: Will Try. Thank you. But, when a status bar is closed, why is the onResume() method not called?

Comment: Notification bar is not an Activity, its a diferent kind of widget, as per android one Acitvity goes into background, when another actvity come on top of it, that not the case here, this is reason why onResume in not called for you.

Comment: Ok. So is there a way to call an activiti's onResume() when a notification is clicked/closed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42915/discussion-between-techfist-and-user2925026)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42921/discussion-between-jonamreddy-and-techfist)